# What alternatives do i have to connect an iOS application with a SoC that uses linux via Bluetooth?

Tags: linux, ios, bluetooth, swift

I'm somewhat lost here.

I need to communicate my iOS app with a SoC that uses a custom Linux distro via Bluetooth 4.0 but I don't know what options do I have. The SoC doesn't have Bluetooth capabilities integrated but it does have a USB port so I can connect a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle to it.

In this case, the iPhone/iPad that runs the app will be the central device and the SoC is going to be a peripheral device. The central device needs to send files and commands to the peripheral device.

The only solution I have come with is to use HCI package (HCItool, HCIconfig, etc) in the SoC to advertise data via the dongle but I'm not sure if after that I can use those tools to establish a connection.